# Android - app list

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app where the user is shown a list of installed applications, each one in a separate check box. If an app is checked, and then later opened, how can I trigger an event when the app that the user selected is opened. I am a complete novice in this area, therefore code or tutorials would be appreciated, as I don't know where to start.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a launcher or does it have a different purpose?

Comment: No its supposed to be just an app with this function

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) `getInstalledApplications()` or `getInstalledPackages()` to get a list of installed apps.

I don't understand the following part of your question:

> If an app is checked, and then later opened, how can I trigger an event when the app that the user selected is opened.

It sounds like you want to open the exact app which the user opens but that's probably not what you mean.